# PHP get object from array

Tags: php

I have some problems with Shopify integration, and I always have this problems with getting info from objects.

> object(Shopify\Object\Product)#32 (3) {
>   ["changedFields":"Shopify\Object\AbstractObject":private]=> array(16)
>   { ["id"]=> int(575833276481) ["title"]=> string(12) "Test Product"
>   ["body_html"]=> NULL ["vendor"]=> string(7) "Printer"
>   ["product_type"]=> string(4) "Test" ["created_at"]=>
>   object(DateTime)#33 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27
>   11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6)
>   "+03:00" } ["handle"]=> string(15) "test-product-24" ["updated_at"]=>
>   object(DateTime)#34 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27
>   11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6)
>   "+03:00" } ["published_at"]=> object(DateTime)#64 (3) { ["date"]=>
>   string(26) "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1)
>   ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+03:00" } ["template_suffix"]=> NULL
>   ["published_scope"]=> string(6) "global" ["tags"]=> string(14) "Barnes
>   & Noble" ["variants"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   object(Shopify\Object\ProductVariant)#65 (3) {
>   ["changedFields":"Shopify\Object\AbstractObject":private]=> array(24)
>   { ["id"]=> int(7196665282625) ["product_id"]=> int(575833276481)
>   ["title"]=> string(13) "Default Title" ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00"
>   ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["position"]=> int(1) ["inventory_policy"]=>
>   string(4) "deny" ["compare_at_price"]=> NULL ["fulfillment_service"]=>
>   string(6) "manual" ["inventory_management"]=> NULL ["option1"]=>
>   string(13) "Default Title" ["option2"]=> NULL ["option3"]=> NULL
>   ["created_at"]=> object(DateTime)#59 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26)
>   "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=>
>   string(6) "+03:00" } ["updated_at"]=> object(DateTime)#53 (3) {
>   ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=>
>   int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+03:00" } ["taxable"]=> bool(true)
>   ["barcode"]=> NULL ["grams"]=> int(0) ["image_id"]=> NULL
>   ["inventory_quantity"]=> int(1) ["weight"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["weight_unit"]=> string(2) "kg" ["old_inventory_quantity"]=> int(1)
>   ["requires_shipping"]=> bool(true) } ["data":protected]=> array(26) {
>   ["barcode"]=> NULL ["compare_at_price"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=>
>   object(DateTime)#59 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27
>   11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6)
>   "+03:00" } ["fulfillment_service"]=> string(6) "manual" ["grams"]=>
>   int(0) ["id"]=> int(7196665282625) ["image_id"]=> NULL
>   ["inventory_management"]=> NULL ["inventory_policy"]=> string(4)
>   "deny" ["old_inventory_quantity"]=> int(1) ["inventory_quantity"]=>
>   int(1) ["inventory_quantity_adjustment"]=> NULL ["metafield"]=> NULL
>   ["option1"]=> string(13) "Default Title" ["option2"]=> NULL
>   ["option3"]=> NULL ["position"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00"
>   ["product_id"]=> int(575833276481) ["requires_shipping"]=> bool(true)
>   ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["taxable"]=> bool(true) ["title"]=> string(13)
>   "Default Title" ["updated_at"]=> object(DateTime)#53 (3) { ["date"]=>
>   string(26) "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1)
>   ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+03:00" } ["weight"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["weight_unit"]=> string(2) "kg" } ["types":protected]=> array(26) {
>   ["barcode"]=> string(6) "string" ["compare_at_price"]=> string(6)
>   "string" ["created_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime"
>   ["fulfillment_service"]=> string(6) "string" ["grams"]=> string(7)
>   "integer" ["id"]=> string(7) "integer" ["image_id"]=> string(7)
>   "integer" ["inventory_management"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["inventory_policy"]=> string(6) "string" ["old_inventory_quantity"]=>
>   string(7) "integer" ["inventory_quantity"]=> string(7) "integer"
>   ["inventory_quantity_adjustment"]=> string(6) "string" ["metafield"]=>
>   string(5) "array" ["option1"]=> string(6) "string" ["option2"]=>
>   string(6) "string" ["option3"]=> string(6) "string" ["position"]=>
>   string(7) "integer" ["price"]=> string(6) "string" ["product_id"]=>
>   string(7) "integer" ["requires_shipping"]=> string(7) "boolean"
>   ["sku"]=> string(6) "string" ["taxable"]=> string(7) "boolean"
>   ["title"]=> string(6) "string" ["updated_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime"
>   ["weight"]=> string(6) "string" ["weight_unit"]=> string(6) "string" }
>   } } ["options"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   object(Shopify\Object\ProductOption)#51 (3) {
>   ["changedFields":"Shopify\Object\AbstractObject":private]=> array(5) {
>   ["id"]=> int(860003369025) ["product_id"]=> int(575833276481)
>   ["name"]=> string(5) "Title" ["position"]=> int(1) ["values"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Default Title" } } ["data":protected]=>
>   array(5) { ["id"]=> int(860003369025) ["product_id"]=>
>   int(575833276481) ["name"]=> string(5) "Title" ["position"]=> int(1)
>   ["values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Default Title" } }
>   ["types":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(7) "integer"
>   ["product_id"]=> string(7) "integer" ["name"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["position"]=> string(7) "integer" ["values"]=> string(5) "array" } }
>   } ["images"]=> array(0) { } ["image"]=> NULL } ["data":protected]=>
>   array(18) { ["body_html"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> object(DateTime)#33
>   (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000"
>   ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+03:00" }
>   ["handle"]=> string(15) "test-product-24" ["id"]=> int(575833276481)
>   ["images"]=> array(0) { } ["options"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   object(Shopify\Object\ProductOption)#51 (3) {
>   ["changedFields":"Shopify\Object\AbstractObject":private]=> array(5) {
>   ["id"]=> int(860003369025) ["product_id"]=> int(575833276481)
>   ["name"]=> string(5) "Title" ["position"]=> int(1) ["values"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Default Title" } } ["data":protected]=>
>   array(5) { ["id"]=> int(860003369025) ["product_id"]=>
>   int(575833276481) ["name"]=> string(5) "Title" ["position"]=> int(1)
>   ["values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Default Title" } }
>   ["types":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(7) "integer"
>   ["product_id"]=> string(7) "integer" ["name"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["position"]=> string(7) "integer" ["values"]=> string(5) "array" } }
>   } ["product_type"]=> string(4) "Test" ["published_at"]=>
>   object(DateTime)#64 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27
>   11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6)
>   "+03:00" } ["published_scope"]=> string(6) "global" ["tags"]=>
>   string(14) "Barnes & Noble" ["template_suffix"]=> NULL ["title"]=>
>   string(12) "Test Product" ["metafields_global_title_tag"]=> NULL
>   ["metafields_global_description_tag"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=>
>   object(DateTime)#34 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27
>   11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6)
>   "+03:00" } ["variants"]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   object(Shopify\Object\ProductVariant)#65 (3) {
>   ["changedFields":"Shopify\Object\AbstractObject":private]=> array(24)
>   { ["id"]=> int(7196665282625) ["product_id"]=> int(575833276481)
>   ["title"]=> string(13) "Default Title" ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00"
>   ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["position"]=> int(1) ["inventory_policy"]=>
>   string(4) "deny" ["compare_at_price"]=> NULL ["fulfillment_service"]=>
>   string(6) "manual" ["inventory_management"]=> NULL ["option1"]=>
>   string(13) "Default Title" ["option2"]=> NULL ["option3"]=> NULL
>   ["created_at"]=> object(DateTime)#59 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26)
>   "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=>
>   string(6) "+03:00" } ["updated_at"]=> object(DateTime)#53 (3) {
>   ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=>
>   int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+03:00" } ["taxable"]=> bool(true)
>   ["barcode"]=> NULL ["grams"]=> int(0) ["image_id"]=> NULL
>   ["inventory_quantity"]=> int(1) ["weight"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["weight_unit"]=> string(2) "kg" ["old_inventory_quantity"]=> int(1)
>   ["requires_shipping"]=> bool(true) } ["data":protected]=> array(26) {
>   ["barcode"]=> NULL ["compare_at_price"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=>
>   object(DateTime)#59 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-27
>   11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6)
>   "+03:00" } ["fulfillment_service"]=> string(6) "manual" ["grams"]=>
>   int(0) ["id"]=> int(7196665282625) ["image_id"]=> NULL
>   ["inventory_management"]=> NULL ["inventory_policy"]=> string(4)
>   "deny" ["old_inventory_quantity"]=> int(1) ["inventory_quantity"]=>
>   int(1) ["inventory_quantity_adjustment"]=> NULL ["metafield"]=> NULL
>   ["option1"]=> string(13) "Default Title" ["option2"]=> NULL
>   ["option3"]=> NULL ["position"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00"
>   ["product_id"]=> int(575833276481) ["requires_shipping"]=> bool(true)
>   ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["taxable"]=> bool(true) ["title"]=> string(13)
>   "Default Title" ["updated_at"]=> object(DateTime)#53 (3) { ["date"]=>
>   string(26) "2018-03-27 11:01:14.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1)
>   ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+03:00" } ["weight"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["weight_unit"]=> string(2) "kg" } ["types":protected]=> array(26) {
>   ["barcode"]=> string(6) "string" ["compare_at_price"]=> string(6)
>   "string" ["created_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime"
>   ["fulfillment_service"]=> string(6) "string" ["grams"]=> string(7)
>   "integer" ["id"]=> string(7) "integer" ["image_id"]=> string(7)
>   "integer" ["inventory_management"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["inventory_policy"]=> string(6) "string" ["old_inventory_quantity"]=>
>   string(7) "integer" ["inventory_quantity"]=> string(7) "integer"
>   ["inventory_quantity_adjustment"]=> string(6) "string" ["metafield"]=>
>   string(5) "array" ["option1"]=> string(6) "string" ["option2"]=>
>   string(6) "string" ["option3"]=> string(6) "string" ["position"]=>
>   string(7) "integer" ["price"]=> string(6) "string" ["product_id"]=>
>   string(7) "integer" ["requires_shipping"]=> string(7) "boolean"
>   ["sku"]=> string(6) "string" ["taxable"]=> string(7) "boolean"
>   ["title"]=> string(6) "string" ["updated_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime"
>   ["weight"]=> string(6) "string" ["weight_unit"]=> string(6) "string" }
>   } } ["vendor"]=> string(7) "Printer" ["image"]=> NULL }
>   ["types":protected]=> array(18) { ["body_html"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["created_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["handle"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["id"]=> string(7) "integer" ["images"]=> string(14) "ProductImage[]"
>   ["options"]=> string(15) "ProductOption[]" ["product_type"]=>
>   string(6) "string" ["published_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime"
>   ["published_scope"]=> string(6) "string" ["tags"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["template_suffix"]=> string(6) "string" ["title"]=> string(6)
>   "string" ["metafields_global_title_tag"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["metafields_global_description_tag"]=> string(6) "string"
>   ["updated_at"]=> string(8) "DateTime" ["variants"]=> string(16)
>   "ProductVariant[]" ["vendor"]=> string(6) "string" ["image"]=>
>   string(12) "ProductImage" } }

and I need to get product_id from this code, but when I try with `echo $product->product_id;` it give's me error like

> Property 'product_id' does not exist for Shopify\Object\Product

I can get only id, title, image and some other info with for example `$product->title` , I tried with `$product->id->title` but still nothing.

Comment: id is a private property. You need to use a getter function to access it. try something like $product->getId() if that even exists. Look at the source code of the object to see if there is a function that does `return $this->id;`

Comment: There's no product_id on product object, it's `Shopify\Object\ProductVariant` object's property.

Comment: echo $product->changedFields->id;

Comment: well the best practice is to use the getId in the object itself.

Comment: `$ProductVariantObj->changeField['product_id']; ` doesn't works? The problem is maybe with the `private` part

Answer (score 0):

according to the API docs , you will notice that the product_id is inside images or variants.
so its more like  $product->variants[0]->product_id

https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product

Comment: I tried now with 
$variants = new Shopify\Object\ProductVariant();
$variants->product_id and $product->variants->product_id
with $variants->product_id give's me just Null, not error, but still don't work.

Comment: Works now with  $product->variants[0]->product_id. Thank's  everyone :)